# Auto-Filling Web Form by an HTML/PHP/JS page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have a very simple issue and I'm looking for a simple way to do that. 
In fact, I'm searching to **auto-fill a Web-Form** from an official webPage of an institution and I would like to do it in Javascript into a webpage which will do it automatically on client-side.

I tried CasperJS/PhantomJS which is very useful to do that but they have to be run by command line and not by a js script.

This webForm is very simple.It has several dropdownList, checkboxes and text input with a simple submit button.

I don't need some detailed code but just the way/tools to achieve that. I'm on it since 2 weeks without any good results.

Comment: Is this web form on someone else's website or your own?

Comment: It sounds like you're describing [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting). Think of the horrible security implications if what you are attempting were possible.

Comment: Provide some context, are you automating a repetitive task or just want to fill out forms quickly?

Comment: Is it just for you, or is it for others? Is it one time only, or multiple times? Is it the same data all the time, or does the data change?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for support. This form is not my Own this is Link Page : [NavCanada](http://wwwapps.tc.gc.ca/saf-sec-sur/2/bsis/s_r.aspx?lang=eng). It's send by POST Method. It's for automating a repetitive Task with data change. It's for automating a human filling each months who have to do it 20 or 30 times eachTime.

Comment: Any Ideas ? It's not possible ?

Comment: Is it Illegal like @digital Chris says ? I would add that I know well the organisation (we're working together) and they are agree with this request method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, this should be done server to server. What you want is a [web service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service).  This way you don't have to have a client machine with a browser sitting open to handle this.

A quicker and dirtier method would be to submit the form data directly to the 3rd party web server via cURL:

https://superuser.com/questions/149329/what-is-the-curl-command-line-syntax-to-do-a-post-request

http://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html

Comment: Thks, I will try and be back.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do that is using Selenium. Use Selenium and you can easily fill out forms of third party.